# High volume UPS shipping solutions

Tags: .net, barcode, ups

This may not be the right place for this question, but the reason I ask here is because I am a programmer and am thinking about implementing my own solution.

We ship about 1000 packages per day using UPS.

Currently there is a lot of manual data entry into the UPS shipping software. The employee will get the package, put it on the scale and input the address and all the necessary details needed to ship the item.

I am thinking of just programmatically creating a 2d barcode that when scanned will automatically fill out the UPS shipping software form.

Has anyone done anything like this in .NET? How do companies usually handle high volume UPS shipping? How do you automate processes?

Comment: Have you contacted Brown? They always ask "what can Brown do for you", now is your chance..seize it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at WorldShip's keyed import. Basically generate a barcode in your application - there are many ways with that for .NET - with a unique key or identifier that looks up the orders in a database. WorldShip's mapping will pull the appropriate record and fill in the values using a CSV file or database.

It would be hard to know what you are integrating with whether a web application or desktop application.

There are other options available too. Generally the "sales rep" with UPS has contacts in the company to help people work better with UPS's systems. See: http://www.ups.com/content/us/en/resources/techsupport/worldship/integrate.html